# need to count the frequency of each terms inside a document

Tags: java, information-retrieval

i need to calculate the frequency of all the terms inside a document. How can i do that ? 
i do not ask for codes. I am just asking for guidance. Actually i am doing some similarity calculation between a document and query. I have calculated the term frequency for the query.
But i do not know how to calculate the tern frequency for EACH words inside a document. Can anyone guide me ? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: can you specify how the document is represented?

Comment: Did you try searching before you posted this? This is asked **a lot**.

Comment: If you're looking for term frequency, [here's a python program](https://github.com/timtrueman/tf-idf/blob/master/tf-idf.py) that will calculate it. You might want to take a look at this.

Comment: the document is represented in a text file. Inside the text files are all words. I have tried searching and i try to avoid hashmap because i do not have sufficient knowledge in it and hope someone might offer me some alternative methods..

Comment: Maps are useful. You should learn them :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap, where key is your term and value - the frequency of it. Each time you see you term you increase the value. After the file is done you have your numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the HashMap to save the values and to go through the file, you can use a [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Java you should definitely stay with `HashMap<String, Integer>`. The terms will be the HashMap keys and the term frequency the value.